# Allow usage of arrow functions in jsx

Tags: reactjs, lint, eslint, jsx

I'm trying to find a rule for .eslintrc file to prevent following error: `JSX props should not use arrow functions`

Stumbled upon this: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

and tried to apply it in my rules like so:

```
"rules"   : {
    "jsx-no-bind": [{
    "allowArrowFunctions": true
  }]
}
```

but doesn't seem to have changed anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your link, the first element in the array you pass to "jsx-no-bind" should be the `<enabled>` value.

So this should work:

```
"rules"   : {
  "jsx-no-bind": [ 
    2, 
    { "allowArrowFunctions": true }
  ]
}
```